# Deepstram.io client has a delay on one Android device. Any ideas on how to avoid it?

Tags: android, node.js, deepstream.io

I tried searching for similar problems, and I found a similar problem here, with no real solution : [socket.io seems to be delayed on my Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598926/socket-io-seems-to-be-delayed-on-my-android-phone)

I'm building a hybrid app (crosswalk), that uses deepstream.io. Clients are connected to to the server (via engine.io) and are subscribed to a few records. The server is updating them, one of the records (timer) is updated every second. This server that is updating the records is a deepstream client in node.js, which is connected via TCP. It works well on different emulators and on Samsung Galaxy Note 2, but on the newest Samsung Galaxy S7 there is always a 3-4 second delay. After this delay all the updated data comes. There were a few times where this delay was not present, but I'm not sure what (if anything) was different.

I'm happy to provide more information, but am not sure what is relevant.
Any ideas on how to avoid this or what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using the latest version of deepstream 2.0 which completely switched to our own messaging layer using websocket and has a new ping-pong roundtrip timer.

Comment: I tried using the latest version, but now I get an error for this line :
deepstream.set( 'httpServer', server );

../server/node_modules/deepstream.io/src/deepstream.io.js:100
  throw new Error( 'Unknown option "' + key + '"' );
  ^

Error: Unknown option "httpServer"
    at Deepstream.set (../server/node_modules/deepstream.io/src/deepstream.io.js:100:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (../server/start.js:205:12)

Comment: the same error is thrown in the Deepstream tutorial https://github.com/deepstreamIO/ds-tutorial-express

Comment: I'm afraid that option has been removed in 2.0

Comment: I'm sorry to say that using the latest version of Deepstream did not work. I've updated to the current latest version (3.0.0 server and 2.2.1 client) and the delay is still there, also on some other devices. Do you have any other ideas what more I could try?